# Is it against good practice to throw twice in a single method, if both exceptions have different conditions?

Tags: java, exception

Let's say we have some method as below:

```
public static void sampleExceptionProblem(String a, String b) throws SomeException {
   if (a == null){
      throw new SomeException("string a is null");
   }

   if (b == null){
      throw new SomeException("string b is null");
   }
}
```

It is my understanding that once an exception is thrown, code execution is stopped and the exception is handled. So would it be correct to assume that the above would check the first if-statement, and if that passes but the second one fails, it would handle that exception. And that there wouldn't be the problem where there are two exceptions that need to be handled at the same time?

Comment: If `a` is `null`, the corresponding exception will be thrown, and the second `if` statement will not be reached. If that is a problem for you, describe how and we can find a way around it.

Comment: Throwing multiple types of exceptions (or the same exception) is fine in practice. I think you might get some opinionated responses in that regard, but depending on your framework it is probably the preferred option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method will throw no more than 1 exception, and it does no exception handling.  If `a == null` it throws an exception at the first if-block and never gets to the second block.  If `a != null` but `b == null` it throws an exception from the second if-block.

"Handling" would require a catch statement somewhere.  Your code fragment does not have one, so there's no handling.  That's not necessarily a problem as long as something higher in the call stack eventually catches and handles.

Also, for a null value you'd usually throw a `NullPointerException` rather than a custom exception, but I assume that was just expedient for you to create a quick example.

Comment: You would not throw an `NullPointerException` if you, for example, wanted the `Exception` to be handled by throwing a **checked** `Exception`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sure - I agree with your comment.  The `NullPointerException` obviously isn't a checked exception.

Comment: @BoristheSpider throwing a checked exception for a null reference would make me cry...

Comment: @assylias surely that depends on the use case, no? If the API consumer is expected to handle and recover from the case where `null` is passed in then a checked exception is most likely appropriate.

Comment: I am with Boris on this one. Why would someone check for null only to throw a `NullPointerException` after?

Answer (score 1):

It's not against good practice. You may throw as many times as you want in a method, but keep in mind that the flow of execution may jump around to `catch` and `finally` blocks so you may not reach other places in your method if you throw.

If an exception is thrown, the execution is stopped and the runtime looks up the stack to see if there is any `catch` block that can handle the exception you've thrown. If there isn't, the whole application crashes. If there is, that `catch` block is executed, and then all the `finally` blocks, starting with the one closest to your method, are called in order. Execution however does not resume, so if `a == null` part throws, the `b == null` part will never thrown.

Now a slightly related discussion about why I'd not throw a `NullPointerException` here (with a slight C# bias):

Personally, if I were you I'd throw an `IllegalArgumentException` here. There have been debates about whether to use a `NullPointerException` or an `IllegalArgumentException` in cases where the parameter of a method is `null`. I normally let the runtime throw NPEs (`NullReferenceException` in C#); I never throw them myself. NPEs suggests the attempt of dereferencing a `null` pointer. Doing it yourself doesn't really respect that: you're not dereferencing anything, so why throw a NPE?

That's largely my personal opinion, becase the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) for `NullPointerException` does say that you may throw it if you want, but I prefer the C# approach, where you have an `ArgumentNullException` for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

If your method's code contains several places which could throw an exception but such code ensures that for all possible paths of execution at maximun one exception will be thrown (per method execution) then that is correct and common practice.
That is the case of your code example. If `a` is `null` then `SomeException("string a is null")` will be thrown and the method will end right there. And code will never reach the 2nd if.
In your code `SomeException("string b is null")` will be thrown if and only if (`a` is not `null`) and (`b` is `null`).

Plenty of methods in the Java API work this way. [Socket.bind(SocketAddress bindpoint)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#bind(java.net.SocketAddress)) in example can throw two different exceptions and the conditions that cause them to be thrown are different. But at most one can get thrown per method execution.

But if your code can throw more than one exception for a single execution of a method then that is something to avoid. Because only one exception will actually reach the caller of the method, so the other one(s) will be supressed.
This can happen in try-with-resources, one might be thrown in the block and another in the implicit finally. It can also happen with explicit finally.
An example of code which would do this would be :

```
public static void sampleExceptionProblem(String a, String b) throws SomeException {
   try
   {
      if (a == null)
         throw new SomeException("string a is null");
   }
   finally 
   {
     if (b == null)
        throw new SomeException("string b is null");
   }
}
```

In that code if both `a` and `b` are `null` `SomeException("string a is null")` will be thrown.
But the method will not end here. `finally` gets executed even in the presence of an exception in the try block. And that will cause `SomeException("string b is null")` to also be thrown. So two exceptions have been thrown but in this case only the second one will reach outside of the method. The first one is supressed, and hence whatever actions needed to be taken to take care of it will not be performed since the calling code will only see the 2nd exception.

With java 7 it is actually possible to see supressed exceptions with [Throwable.getSupressed()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed--). But even so it is better to avoid supressed exceptions.